# DNS and nginx server setup causes slow server and 502 response

Tags: php, nginx, configuration, dns

I'm setting up a new server with Ubuntu 18.04.1 Nginx 1.14.0 and PHP 7.2.7    Everything works fine except a test page where I set up a lot of broken links to missing images. 
Edit: I decided to ask [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362123/php-and-nginx-server-slow-when-combining-ipv4-with-ipv6) based on the conclusions of this discussion that there probably is a DNS misconfiguration.

It seems to take forever for the server to realise they are missing and respond to the http request. Some missing files give a HTTP status of 404 and some give 502. What causes these delays and 502 errors? Did I do something wrong in the nginx or php configuration?

On my old server I have the exact same page which loads very quick. There must be a difference in server setup that I would like to solve.

Edit: the server doesn't recognize the the IPv6 address being server1.eu but accessing the IPv4 address immediately shows https://server1.eu

The zone file records:

```
AAAA    server1.eu  directs to the IPv6 address 
A   server1.eu  directs to the IPv4 address
```

Dayo suggested the hosts file might be a problem, however the problem persists if the hosts file is emptied all together. Here is the contents:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
(the IPv6 address) localhost
127.0.1.1 host.server1.eu


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

The nginx server configuration, when I remove the line "listen [::]:443 ssl http2;" everything works fine:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server1.eu/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server1.eu/privkey.pem;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        server_name server1.eu;
        root /var/www/server1/webroot;
        index index.php index.html index.htm ;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    #   keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip             on;
    gzip_comp_level  2;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types       text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 500; #gateway probleem
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 25;
    send_timeout 10;
}
```

The php app I use is Joomla 3.8.11 with a custom script to show a custom error page:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
echo file_get_contents('https://server1.eu/404-page-not-found'); 
exit;
```

After removing file_get_contents there are no errors anymore. However I'm wondering why, as it used to work fine on my old server (see edit above about DNS). Also I need this script to properly show a HTTP status 404 and a custom error page without changing the addressbar.

A part of the nginx error.log:

```
2018/08/30 16:25:27 [error] 29228#29228: *76 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 2a02:a440:91e3:1:4481:654b:a3e8:9617, server: server1.eu, request: "GET /images/klanten1/JHoogeveen.gif HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "server1.eu", referrer: "https://server1.eu/portfolio-2"
```

Messages from the php7.2-fpm.log (there are a lot similar lines)

```
[30-Aug-2018 16:16:08] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (15), consider raising it
[30-Aug-2018 16:16:27] WARNING: [pool www] child 29026, script '/var/www/server1/webroot/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (22.937711 sec), terminating
[30-Aug-2018 16:16:27] WARNING: [pool www] child 29245 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 20.490546 seconds from start
[30-Aug-2018 16:16:27] NOTICE: [pool www] child 29263 started
```

Below is the timeline of HTTP requests and replies, that shows the requests on non-existent files and the response of the server, some give a 404 which is good, some give 502 bad gateway (on my old server they are all 404's).
Edit: There are fifteen 502 responses, which number is the maximum amount of concurrent PHP processes as Miknik remarked in his answer.

```
GET https://server1.eu/portfolio-2 [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 132ms]
GET https://server1.eu/templates/purity_iii/css/bootstrap.css [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 40ms]
GET https://server1.eu/templates/system/css/system.css [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 50ms]
GET https://server1.eu/templates/purity_iii/css/template.css [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 50ms]
GET https://server1.eu/templates/purity_iii/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 50ms]
GET https://server1.eu/templates/purity_iii/css/layouts/corporate.css [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 50ms]
GET https://server1.eu/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js?48b6d1b3850bca834b403c58682b4579 [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 60ms]
GET https://server1.eu/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js?48b6d1b3850bca834b403c58682b4579 [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 60ms]
GET https://server1.eu/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js?48b6d1b3850bca834b403c58682b4579 [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 60ms]
GET https://server1.eu/media/system/js/caption.js?48b6d1b3850bca834b403c58682b4579 [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 70ms]
GET https://server1.eu/plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js? 8b6d1b3850bca834b403c58682b4579 [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 80ms]
GET https://server1.eu/plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/js/jquery.tap.min.js [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 80ms]
GET https://server1.eu/plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/js/script.js [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 70ms]
GET https://server1.eu/plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/js/menu.js [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 70ms]
GET https://server1.eu/templates/purity_iii/js/script.js [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 70ms]
GET https://server1.eu/plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/js/nav-collapse.js [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 70ms]
GET https://server1.eu/templates/purity_iii/css/custom-vuyk.css [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 70ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/schipper2.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 23988ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Kuiper.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 24038ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/WindMatch.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 24008ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Tuinland.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 24018ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Wezenberg.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 24038ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Morgenster.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 23998ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Harrie-boerhof.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 24028ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Lococensus.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 23998ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/JHoogeveen.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 23978ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/DeDeur.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 23988ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Runhaar.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 23958ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Schunselaar-schildersbedrijf.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 23948ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Capelle.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 23958ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Distantlake.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 24038ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Eikenaar.gif [HTTP/2.0 502 Bad Gateway 24018ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/FFWD.gif [HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found 26274ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Veltec.gif [HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found 26791ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Heutink.gif [HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found 26811ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Lindeboom.gif [HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found 26777ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/aataxi.gif [HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found 26828ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Aewind.gif [HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found 26811ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/klanten1/Praatmaatgroep.gif [HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found 26800ms]
GET https://server1.eu/media/system/css/system.css [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 20ms]
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 jquery-migrate.min.js:2:542
GET https://server1.eu/images/logo.gif [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 20ms]
GET https://server1.eu/images/reclame-en-communicatie.gif [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 20ms]
GET https://server1.eu/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 40ms]
GET https://server1.eu/templates/purity_iii/fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 70ms]
```

fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

php.ini

```
[PHP]

engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = -1
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_get_handler,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,pcntl_async_signals,
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
html_errors = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 28M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 20M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
cli_server.color = On
date.timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam"

[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off

[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.sid_length = 26
session.trans_sid_tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="
session.sid_bits_per_character = 5

[Assertion]
zend.assertions = -1

[mbstring]
mbstring.func_overload = 0

[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
```

Comment: How your PHP app reacts to unknown routes? When file/image is not available, request is passed to PHP application, it looks like it take way too much time to respond with 404.

Comment: It is Joomla 3.8.11, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I made a html testpage without php on https://test.vuyk.eu/portfolio-3.html
This gives the same results

Comment: Do you have custom 404 page? Maybe it's trying to connect to some dead/slow service, or performs some kind of slow search and times out on generation of 404 page.

Comment: That was a good suggestion. I use a script to show a custom error page: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); echo file_get_contents('https://test.vuyk.eu/404-page-not-found'); exit; After removing that it works good and no errors. However I'm wondering why, as this script used to work fine on my old server and I need it to show the custom page. I'll use this to edit the question.

Comment: If I understand you correctly. To render 404 page you download current 404 page (`file_get_contents('https://test.vuyk.eu/404-page-not-found'); `). This is loop, to render page you try to fetch page you try to render. https://test.vuyk.eu/404-page-not-found renders correctly(and fast) are you sure your custom script looks as you provided? Maybe you have custom 404 configured on loadbalancer or proxy, theh you might try removing `echo file_get_contents('https://test.vuyk.eu/404-page-not-found'); ` line

Comment: The Joomla system serves a file named error.php in case of a 404. To customize the 404 page I have to insert this script in error.php to load 'https://test.vuyk.eu/404-page-not-found', this is not a loop. This is an existing page on the same server. Yes it is literally the script as inserted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179203/discussion-between-mleko-and-c-a-vuyk).

Comment: After accepting the answer of mleko, I discovered that, on my old server, the exact same page that causes errors on the new server, loads without a problem. So it's not just too much http requests. There must be a difference in server setup that I would like to solve. The answer of Dayo points to a problem in DNS setup. So I unaccepted the answer and hope someone can give a definite clue to whats going on.

Comment: `when I remove the line "listen [::]:443 ssl http2;" everything works fine` which means it's an IPv6 issue? Try to access `https://[2a03:b0c0:0:1010::190:6001]/images/klanten1/schipper2.gif` in a browser and it fails, but 37.139.19.66 works. Are you sure that is the correct IPv6 address.

Comment: yes, 2a03:b0c0:0:1010::190:6001 is the right IP.
But when accessing this IP, there is a certificate mismatch notification.

Comment: When accessing this IP, there is a certificate mismatch notification. This is strange because the nginx server setup (see contents listed above in the question) leads both IPv4 and IPv6 to the same certificate.

Answer (score 8):

Heres whats happening.

It says in your error log `server reached pm.max_children setting (15), consider raising it`

So the max.children limit of 15 means PHP-FPM will stop launching processes once an app has 15 processes running, and any more requests for processes which come in will be queued until one of the previous processes ends.

You are using a php script to generate a 404 page, you then load a page with a load of broken links, your Nginx try files directive ends with a php script:

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`

From the Nginx docs that means:

> If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri
>   specified in the last parameter is made.

So for every broken link you just added an extra php process to the queue. If you count your 502 errors in the log you'll see there are 15. Because Nginx looks for 15 `/index.php?$args` which it can't find so tries to display a 404 which guess what? Is generated in php and now everything is broken.

15 processes which cant return 404 because the process limit has been reached and they each need another process to generate a 404 page, so until they time out no more processes for you.

The whole idea of serving a 404 page this way is crazy anyway. It's a static page, you should be serving it from Nginx because web servers are really really good at delivering static content fast, passing it to php, which in turn requests it from your own server again makes absolutely no sense.

Download your custom page to a file:

```
curl -o /var/www/vuyk.eu/webroot/404.html https://test.vuyk.eu/404-page-not-found
```

Now add an error page directive in your Nginx conf:

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
```

and now you have Nginx serving a custom error page without changing the client url and absolutely no load on your server.

Comment: That's really good stuff!  I was about to suggest raising max.children when you swooped in with this really excellent explanation!

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of the workings of Nginx. Yes, I understand that process and surely the setup now isn't how it should be with the broken links and the script in error.php and all. But why does my new server choke on this and my old server doesn't blink an eye. The processing of the broken links works without the long delay.

Old server: https://vuyk.eu/portfolio-2
New server: https://test.vuyk.eu/portfolio-2

Watch the loading times and HTTP responses!
Also, when I remove the line "listen [::]:443 ssl http2;" in the server setup, the problem is over.

Answer (score 6):

It's seems that images you try to load are unavailable and requests are passed to PHP where 404 page is generated. Your custom 404 page is fetching resources via http

```
echo file_get_contents('https://test.vuyk.eu/404-page-not-found');
```

If this fetch is slow your script might execute for very long time which might lead to timeouts. Also this might result in requests piling up and draining server resources.

Try to replace this fetch with something faster, you can try to read/include 404 page data directly from filesystem.

Comment: Now I changed the script in error.php 
Removed file_get_contents and inserted if (($this->error->code) == '404') {
header('Location: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=75');
exit;
}

Comment: After accepting the answer, I discovered that on my old server, when I have the exact same page (vuyk.eu/portfolio-2)
with missing images which uses the file_get_contents, it loads very quick.
There must be a difference in server setup that I would like to solve.
So, I try to find the reason why file_get_contents is so slow

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk did you had some kind of cache or reverse proxy before? Varnish, CloudFlare?

Comment: No, none at all!

Answer (score 4):

There are two broad possibilities as to why this is slow on the new server.

1. Problems with Webserver / PHP
2. Problems with DNS

To troubleshoot, enter the command line on your server and try to fetch a missing file using wget or cUrl. If you get a response as fast as you expect, then you most likely have an issue with your Webserver / PHP. If it is also slow, then the issue is with the DNS setup on your new server.

In any case, it appears that using `file_get_contents` for external URLs can lead to funky results. (Yes, The files are on your server but as you have a full url, it is treated like an external url).

So instead of ...

```
echo file_get_contents('https://test.vuyk.eu/404-page-not-found');
```

use

```
echo file_get_contents('/server/path/to/404-page-not-found');
```

If you can't do this because `404-page-not-found` is not a physical file and has to be run through Joomla to be generated, then why not use cUrl instead? This is specifically for 'external' files.

```
function curlFile($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  $ret = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $ret;
}

echo curlFile('https://test.vuyk.eu/404-page-not-found');
```

Note that if you found a DNS issue, you will need to resolve that notwithstanding.

Comment: Hi Dayo, thank you for your suggestions. 
I tested from command line wget - that works fast without problems.
The page is not a physical file so /server/path will not work, when I try curl, this is also very slow and gives 502 for the image files (I have it now on the test.vuyk.eu so you may check this in your browser).
Which DNS problem would you suggest? test.vuyk.eu points to the right IP and the nginx server setup seems ok to me.
I feel the problem may be in the nginx.conf or php.ini

Comment: I find DNS to be a dark art but I did move servers a couple of years ago and some things became excruciately slow. Yum for instance took ages to run until I stumbled on a solution which was that I needed to swap the order in which IPv4 and IPv6 addresses where being checked in my `/etc/hosts` file. Basically, what was happening was that IPv6 was being checked "x" number of times with "y sec" delay between each attempt before it switched to IPv4. By getting it to check IPv4 first, these slowness issues were resolved. You likely have similar going on. Could be in the opposite order in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I emptied the whole hosts file (which should be safe according to the man) but this didn't bring change unfortunately.

Comment: Perhaps swapping the order would be better. Whether the issue is with the hosts file on not, your issue seems to be a DNS issue as opposed to a webserver issue.

Comment: I added an edit to the question with the contents of the hosts file. IPv4 isn't mentioned in there, what would you suggest to swap?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is IPv4. I don't know enough about the host file to say for certain, but I think yours is quite misconfigured and you might need to seek help from your host. In any case, at least you have things working in the meanwhile.

Comment: Your DNS suggestion was the best so far I think. The server should run fine without anything in the hosts file. That was tested.

Comment: Probably a combination of issues as the answer pointing to the try_files setup makes a strong point.

Comment: Yes but the bottomline is that same thing on the old server with only IPv4 works well and disabling IPv6 on new server works well also.